# Multiplexer instead of multiple AND gates?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, logic-gates

I have to use a s**tandard 74hc595 Shift Register** and monitor all of its outputs that I have previously set at my will as 1s and 0s. Because I have certain constrains on the monitor lines that cannot be tackled, I considered to use logic gates and ( lets say AND gate ) and by driving all outputs to HIGH connect expect a HIGH signal as well. If any output showcases any problems and changes between its states (radiation testing will be performed) then the last output will show a LOW signal and therefore I will know that something is wrong.

I want however to use less ICs than the current design ( 2 gates ). Can the multiplexer help me anyhow?
Again, I have 8 outputs. All HIGHs and I want a HIGH when all are OK and a zero when either them outputs go LOW.
**Multiplexer as a milti-input gate.**

Comment: Please show us a schematic of what you planned to do with the AND gates so we can get a better idea of what you are doing. Is this static or dynamic testing? If dynamic, describe the stimulus. What information do you want at the end, do you need to know which output failed or just if any output failed? Exactly what kind of radiation testing?

Comment: There are ANDs with 8 inputs, for example 4068.

Comment: sounds like a job for wired OR configuration ... eight open collector outputs connected to one pullup resistor

Comment: One problem here: Suppose the device being tested fails "stuck high". You really need to be doing comparisons between expected and actual outputs for multiple inputs and for both output polarities to catch all failures. That probably means comparing with XOR gates rather than AND gates. Or just capturing the output to a computer and doing the comparison in software.

Comment: You need to explain further. 1. You say you can set the output bits to 1 or 0 ....but only talk about testing all ones? 2. is the sensing circuit also exposed to radiation? 3. is this a static radiation test or pulsed? 4. are you testing the device 'in circuit' or standalone?

Comment: ![This is a reference schema](https://gitlab.com/acubesat/obc/organizational/uploads/106906f9e3b6a6542c162a57db39b7e3/and.png)
The test will be realized in static mode, The DUT shift register will be a standalone and fo obvious reasons the beam won't include the gates. The kind of gate doesn;t really matter. I just want to get the least number of signals out of the VAC, There is a mcu that could get the signals but it will be out of the VAC as well so that beats the  purpose once again.